# Joint Control in Baxter using ROS in C++

Tags: ros, c++, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am a beginner in ROS. I am trying to control Baxter Robot using ROS in C++ language. I want to move Baxter in Joint Level Control by providing each joint angels. Since, this is my learning phase, so I am avoiding python API for now. However I have already tried python API from the Baxter official website.

Well, I tried printing the current joint angles by subscribing to `/robot/joint_states` topic in the following way `node.subscribe("/robot/joint_states",100,printJointStates);`. It works perfectly. Now, I wanted to move the joints. So I tried to publish the data into `/robot/limb/right/joint_command` topic. Below is the complete code-

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Initializen the ros
    ros::init(argc, argv, "move_joints");

    //Declare the node handle
    ros::NodeHandle node;
    
    //Decleare a joint state publisher
    ros::Publisher joint_pub = node.advertise<sensor_msgs::JointState>("/robot/limb/right/joint_command",10);
    
    //Define the joint state
    sensor_msgs::JointState joint_state;
  
    joint_state.name[0] = "right_e0";
    joint_state.name[1] = "right_e1";
    joint_state.name[2] = "right_s0";
    joint_state.name[3] = "right_s1";
    joint_state.name[4] = "right_w0";
    joint_state.name[5] = "right_w1";
    joint_state.name[6] = "right_w2";

    joint_state.position[0] = 0.0;
    joint_state.position[1] = 0.0;
    joint_state.position[2] = 0.0;
    joint_state.position[3] = 0.0;
    joint_state.position[4] = 0.0;
    joint_state.position[5] = 0.0;
    joint_state.position[6] = 0.0;

    //command the robot to move
    joint_pub.publish(joint_state);
    
    ros::spinOnce();

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles without any error but shows following error in the run time-
segmentation fault (core dumped)

I suspect that the `JointState` is not properly defined.
Please note that I am using ROS Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit OS. I am using Gazebo simulator to test this code.

I am unable to proceed further. Please provide your suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221736/joint-control-in-baxter-using-ros-in-c++/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2015-11-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [justinkgoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27238/justinkgoh/) on 2016-07-05**:
Hi, I am wondering if you could send me your code for the subscriber. I am also a beginner and trying to get a subscriber and publisher thing going as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Messages in ROS are compiled into compatible C++ structures. Here `joint_state.name` is a `std::vector<std::string>` and `joint_state.position` is a `std::vector<double>`. When adding elements to these structures, you need to use the standard methods of adding elements to a C++ vector, such as 
`joint_state.position.push_back(0.0);`

or by first resizing the `joint_state.position` vector: 
`joint_state.position.resize(7);  // and then index as you do above` 
`joint_state.position[0] = 0.0;`

I happen to have a Github Gist that commands Baxter's arms with C++, quite similar to your code (sans the coredump :)

https://gist.github.com/rethink-imcmahon/237e6be4d29d812577be

One potential "gotcha" here is that you will need to command Baxter's arms at a **rate greater than 5Hz**. Otherwise, they will revert back into position mode and hold their place. This is a safety feature.

And for a few helpful links -

- ROS Message inner workings: http://wiki.ros.org/msg
- Reference for C++ vectors: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/
- Baxter's Arm Control Mode Details: http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Arm_Control_Modes

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2015-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2015-11-30**:
Thank you very much. Happy to see a detailed answer. I appreciate it!!!